# Pythonic way to generate a list of a certain size with no duplicates?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a list of `(x, y)` tuples of size `num_cities` with the constraint that no two tuples are the same. Is there a shorter, Pythonic way to do this using a set comprehension or `itertools`? I currently have:

```
def make_random_cities(num_cities, max_x, max_y):    
    cities = set()
    while len(cities) < num_cities:
        x, y = randint(0, max_x), randint(0, max_y)
        cities.add((x, y))
    return list(cities)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the maximum values aren't too large to store the complete set of possibilities in memory (and it won't take forever to generate them), [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can be used effectively here:

```
import itertools
import random

def make_random_cities(num_cities, max_x, max_y):
    return random.sample(list(itertools.product(range(max_x+1), range(max_y+1))), num_cities)
```

If the `product` of the inputs gets too large though, you could easily exceed main memory; in that case, your approach of looping until you get sufficient unique results is probably the best approach.

You could do samples of each `range` independently and then combine them together, but that would add uniqueness constraints to each axis, which I'm guessing you don't want.

For this specific case (unique numbers following a predictable pattern), you could use a trick to make this memory friendly while still avoiding the issue of arbitrarily long loops. Instead of taking the `product` of two `range`s, you'd generate a single `range` (or in Py2, `xrange`) that encodes both unique values from the `product` in a single value:

```
def make_random_cities(num_cities, max_x, max_y):
    max_xy = (max_x+1) * (max_y+1)
    xys = random.sample(range(max_xy), num_cities)
    return [divmod(xy, max_y+1) for xy in xys]
```

This means you have no large intermediate data to store (because Py3 `range`/Py2 `xrange` are "virtual" sequences, with storage requirements unrelated to the range of values they represent, and `random.sample` produces samples without needing to read all the values of the underlying sequence).

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is probably good if the number of cities is much smaller than `max_x * max_y`. If they're closer together though, it may waste a lot of time generating duplicate coordinates.

An alternative approach would be to generate all possible coordinates and then sample from them:

```
possible_coords = list(itertools.product(range(max_x), range(max_y))
sample = random.sample(possible_coords, len(cities))
```

Generating the list of will always take `O(max_x * max_y)`, but it won't get worse if the number of cities increases.